# Check if a number is in a string

Tags: hibernate, jpa, querydsl

I have a `varchar` field like this `1-2-55-9` , numbers delimited by `-`

How can make a query in `hibernate` or `querydsl` or `jpa` to check if a number is in this field ?

```
select * from x where TEST
```

What test to do if for example `55 -> yes return record` , `5 -> no` , `7-> no`

Comment: "a number"? what number? you mean if the third component of this string is a particular number? Look at JPQL "LIKE" keyword

Comment: i put a example in my question

Comment: An example? You mean "55" is your example ? you don't say which part of the number needs to be 55 in your "example". As said, look at JPQL keyword LIKE

Comment: for example `1-2-55-9` if we split this string we got `1` `2` `55` `9` , no i want to search if this field contain the number `5` or any other number its depend on query args

Answer (score 0):

There are a few solutions to your problem and the optimal one depends on what are all the possible values of `varchar`.
In general you need to use *string pattern matching*.

Assuming that `varchar` contains:

```
1-2-55-9
7-8-55-5
3-A-55-4
```

you can use the following string pattern:

```
_-_-55-_  // underscore wildcard character _ substitutes a single character
```

however it will stop working in cases like these:

```
1-2-55-99
1-22-55-9
11-2-55-99
123-200-55-A
```

To be more flexible you can replace the above string pattern with

```
%-%-55-%  // percent wildcard character % substitutes multiple characters
```

---

As suggested in the comments above JPQL `LIKE` expression is the way you should follow, for example:

```sql
SELECT e FROM MyEntity e WHERE e.varchar LIKE '_-_-55-_'   -- or '%-%-55-%'
```

Optionally you can experiment with JPQL `LOCAL` expression, for example:

```sql
SELECT e FROM MyEntity e WHERE LOCATE('-55-', e.varchar, 3) > 0
```

Playing with these two queries you may see the difference in performance, flexibility and how JPA translates a given query to native SQL.